# json to php as utf-8 from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I wanted to know how I can make a jQuery post with the JSON set as UTF-8. Right now this is my JSON that I'm sending to `testimage.php`. Would I have to do this on the client side? server side with PHP (`json_decode()`)? Both?

This is what I want to post:

```
{
    "ff": "news-gothic-std",
    "a": "right",
    "s": 22,
    "words": [{
        "t": "trioSkincare's",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }, {
        "t": " 9th",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }, {
        "t": " Anniversary",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }, {
        "t": "JohnÂ Â Â ",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }, {
        "t": " Smith",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }, {
        "t": "\n",
        "c": "#99cccc",
        "fs": "normal",
        "fw": "700"
    }],
    "w": 277,
    "h": 46
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this" in the context of "Would I have to do this on the client side"? It's difficult to work out what you want to do. Also, for future questions, you need to format any code you post in a way that's actually readable.

Comment: JSON is utf-8 by default (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). But you also need to send the correct header: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. And yes, you only need `json_decode` on the server side.

Comment: where do i set : Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8. Is this on the server side as well?

Comment: @PraneetSharma Depends on how you perform the post (I could tell you more if you showed the code). Since you work with jQuery, I assume you do it with `$.ajax()`. It has the attribute `contentType`: `$.ajax({ contentType : "application/json";})` - jQuery sends it in UTF8 by default (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing make sure your page has:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

this will make all the data posted as JSON utf-8. And if you are going to store that data in a table make sure that that tables Collation is set to utf8_general_ci